# notifications in android don't work when logout and re-login

Tags: android, session, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I send notifications per 24 hours. It works perfect. I have AlarmReceiver class and i set my alarm repeatedly in my setAlarm() method. The problem is when i logout and re-login(same or different account and without closing app), app is not send notification at all. When i close the app and re-run it works again.

Why it isn't working when i logout and re-login. Any thoughts? Thank you, best regards.

AlarmReceiver Class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Selamlar")
            .setContentText("bildirim geldi!")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());



}
```

Comment: code from edmt dev youtube channel

Comment: First, this code won't trigger notification on Android O+.

Comment: Second, what are you doing on login and logout ? your question is vague

Comment: this code was just a receiver. my setAlarm() method trigger notifications. I cleared sharedpreferences when logout with editor.remove. Then it solved.